# BroadcastReceiver in android 7.0

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working with a broadcastreceiver in android 7 but it is not working properly so Do we need to register the broadcastreceiver using registereceiver() inorder to work with broadcast reviver in android 7.

Comment: What do you mean by working properly ?

Comment: "Do we need to register the broadcastreceiver using registereceiver() inorder to work with broadcast reviver in android 7" -- not normally. A [mcve] and a more detailed explanation of "not working properly" would help us help you better.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 changes related to broadcast receivers in android 7:

1. Apps targeting Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher do not receive **CONNECTIVITY_ACTION** broadcasts if they declare their broadcast receiver in the manifest. Apps will still receive **CONNECTIVITY_ACTION** broadcasts if they register their BroadcastReceiver with `Context.registerReceiver()` and that context is still valid.
2. The system no longer sends **ACTION_NEW_PICTURE** or **ACTION_NEW_VIDEO** broadcasts. This optimization affects all apps, not only those targeting Android 7.0.